# Can I log CO-Pilot and Multi-Pilot hours as a safety pilot?

Tags: logging, caa-uk-regulations, uk

I am working for a UK airline as a First Officer. I have in my roster some flights where I am acting as safety pilot for FO's conducting line training. I am wondering if I can log my hours as CO-Pilot and Multi-Pilot time as well as include it in my Total time. I am UKCAA licensed so regulations from the UK authority on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please describe who is sitting in what seats & who is doing what specific duties during the time that you are "acting as safety pilot for FO's conducting line training."

Comment: I am an FO acting as safety pilot for the flight sitting in the Jump seat. Captain is still there as PIC and FO in the right hand seat on line training flights. My primary role is to ensure no called or actions are missed and assist with anything where the work load get to high for the training FO

Comment: As far as I know, I think I can still log it as co-pilot + multi-pilot as I am a required member of the crew as the 'FO' has not been signed off yet